# Join three tables based on a single common column and select max date value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have SQL Server tables defined like this:

```
create table users
(
    user_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    name varchar(200),
    username varchar(200),
    password varchar(50),
    encrypted_password varchar(100),
    email varchar(30),
    phone_no int,
    address varchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)    
)

create table electricity
(
    table_name VARCHAR(50),
    electricity_bill_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    billing_month_year varchar(50),
    units_consumed int,
    user_id int,
    account_number varchar(100),
    amount varchar(100),
    due_date  varchar(100),  
    PRIMARY KEY(electricity_bill_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)     
);

insert into electricity (table_name, billing_month_year, units_consumed, user_id, account_number, amount, due_date) 
values ('Electricity','2015-05-22',13,1,'acc01',2500,'2015-06-22');

create table water
(
    table_name VARCHAR(10),
    water_bill_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    billing_month_year_date varchar(50),
    units_consumed int,
    user_id int,
    account_number varchar(100),
    amount varchar(100),
    due_date varchar(100), 
    PRIMARY KEY(water_bill_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)    
)

insert into water(table_name, billing_month_year_date, units_consumed, user_id, account_number, amount, due_date)
values ('Water','2015-04-22',17,1,'acc01',2500,'2015-05-14');

create table telephone
(
    table_name VARCHAR(10),
    telecom_bill_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    bill_Period varchar(100),
    user_id int,
    account_number varchar(100),
    amount varchar(100),
    issued_date varchar(50),
    due_date varchar(50), 
    PRIMARY KEY(telecom_bill_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)    
)

insert into telephone(table_name, bill_Period, user_id, account_number, amount, issued_date, due_date)
values ('Telephone', '2015-04-22', 1, 'acc01', 2500, '2015-05-14', '2015-05-18');
```

The problem is that I want to join `electricity`, `water` and `telephone` tables based on the `user id` that I need to pass in to the query.

And also I want to pick the **maximum due_date** from the three tables. But, I've some issues with it.

Please can somebody help me.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `table_name` column in each table? Seems rather pointless - the table's name alraedy defines what table it is.....

Comment: @marc_s no that's just for testing with an application purpose. not relevant to here specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `outer apply`:

```
select u.*, e.*, w.*, t.*
from users u outer apply
     (select top 1 e.*
      from electricity e
      where e.user_id = u.user_id
      order by e.due_date desc
     ) e outer apply
     (select top 1 w.*
      from water w
      where w.user_id = u.user_id
      order by w.due_date desc
     ) w outer appy
     (select top 1 t.*
      from telephone t
      where t.user_id = u.user_id
      order by t.due_date desc
     ) t 
where u.user_id = @user_id;
```

With indexes on `(user_id, due_date)` on all three tables, the query should have very good performance as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(e.due_date) AS ElectricityDueDate, MAX(w.due_date) AS WaterDueDate, MAX(t.due_date) AS TelephoneDueDate 
FROM user u, electricity e, water w, telephone t
WHERE u.user_id=@user_id AND
e.user_id=u.user_id AND
w.user_id=u.user_id AND
t.user_id=u.user_id AND
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

However, to do so you should change the due_date type to DATE, in this way
you can compute the max value.